# How do I get around apt forcing me to upgrade packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell

I am New to Linux, and I have tried Customisation on Linux using Gnome Extensions and a package called libmutter which has an older version on my system

whenever I try to download any package I get this error -

```
  ~ sudo apt install peek      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-mutter-10 : Depends: libmutter-10-0 (= 42.9-0ubuntu5) but 42.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: libmutter-10-0 (>= 42.9) but 42.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 peek : Depends: ffmpeg
        Depends: libkeybinder-3.0-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

but when I run sudo apt -fix-broken install, it upgrades the libmutter to its latest version and then the package stops working but I can install other packages normally
and i have to manually dpkg it from its zip files and logout to apply changes

is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install peek
```

You need to edit your sources.list as follows, `sudo apt edit-sources`:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse universe main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse universe main restricted
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install peek
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after enabling the universe repository, is there a way to tell apt that one package (libmutter in this case) needs to have an older version for the application

Comment: @JugalGadhavi See my edit.